# "Code Too Large" Error is coming when so many values initialized to array in Resource File

Tags: java, resources

I am trying to get values from a resource class file where I need to initialize huge amount of values to an array of `static final Object[][]`, which resulting in "Code Too Large" error when compiled.

Searched for this in the forum, everywhere it is said like split your code. But, I would like to avoid having multiple resource files. Can we do the same splitting within the same resource file by using different classes/variables/methods and all.

and here is the code structure sample which I used

```
package resources;

import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

public class Labels extends ListResourceBundle
{
  static final Object[][] contents = { { "RD.Empno.label", "Employee No" }, 
                                       { "RD.Ename.label", "Employee Name" }, 
                                       { "RD.Sal.label", "Salary" },
                                       { "RD.Deptno.label", "Department No" }
                                     };

  public Object[][] getContents()
  {
    return contents;
  }
}
```

Kindly suggest the way to proceed with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because the compile has a limit of 64KB of byte code and when you build an array this way it actually set each value in a method.

A much cleaner way is to use a text file which you parse to load it or you can create a String which you parse.  This will make the code much smaller.

```
static final String[][] contents = parse("RD.Empno.label, Employee No\n"
                                   + "RD.Ename.label, Employee Name\n" 
                                   + "RD.Sal.label, Salary\n",
                                   + "RD.Deptno.label, Department No");
```

where parse looks like

```
static String[][] parse(String... strs) {
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s: strs) {
        String[] lines = s.split("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) 
           list.add(lines[i].split(", ", 2));
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()][]);
}
```

This way your array can use up to 2 GB and still fit.

Comment: thanks all. I shall try the procedure mentioned by Peter and will come back.

Comment: I tried the way u suggested, it worked well with the sample data (4 set of values) which I provided here but thrown "constant string too long" error when used with original data which is huge amount, around 22000 set of values.. could you please suggest any other way of splitting the same.

Comment: @SandeepKGujje you can split it into many Strings which are not too large.  The best solution is to use an external text file.  This makes editing the file easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final Object[][] contents = new Object[xlength][ylength];
```

Then, if possible, use a loop to fill in the bundle with similarly-structured data. If you can't, you can fill in some of your contents here, and some of your contents in another class. Or, store your data in another file (not a class file), and read from it.